# Cannot add security group defined in remote server to folder permissions of same server. "Some or all identity reference could not be translated"

Tags: c#, directoryservices

I am trying to add user account group defined in remote server to folder in remote server.

```
public static void SetFolderPermission(string folderPath,string account)
{
    var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
    var directorySecurity = directoryInfo.GetAccessControl();

    var fileSystemRule = new FileSystemAccessRule(account, 
                            FileSystemRights.Read, 
                            InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit |
                            InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, 
                            PropagationFlags.None,
                            AccessControlType.Allow);

    directorySecurity.AddAccessRule(fileSystemRule);
    directoryInfo.SetAccessControl(directorySecurity);
}
```

I am able to add accounts with `domainname\accountname`, but I am unable to add local account group defined in remote server.

Comment: Can you also include the actual (literal) parameters that you are sending to this function? (like 'C:\' and 'MyMachine\Sandeep')

Comment: Yes, that's a fact - **machine local** users and groups **cannot** be added to server-based groups.

Comment: I am able to add useraccount like "domainname\accountname" to \\server1\D$\folder1 .But I cannot add group like "server1\group1" where group1 is local to server1 .

Comment: I had created a security group in remoteserver, I just wanted to add that SG to folderpermissions of same server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to solve by changing principal context to server.

```
public void SetFolderPermission(string folderPath,string account,string server)
{
   var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
   var directorySecurity = directoryInfo.GetAccessControl();
   PrincipalContext pt = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, server);

    using (GroupPrincipal val = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pt, account))
{

    FileSystemAccessRule fileSystemRule = new FileSystemAccessRule(val.Sid,
                                                     FileSystemRights.Read,
                                                     InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit |
                                                     InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit,
                                                     PropagationFlags.None,
                                                     AccessControlType.Allow);//var

    directorySecurity.AddAccessRule(fileSystemRule);
    directoryInfo.SetAccessControl(directorySecurity);

    MessageBox.Show("done");
}
}
```